# Gerar notificação na plataforma web toda vez que chegar um novo formulario

Tags: html, web-service, aplicação-web, jquery-datatables, push-notification

Estou desenvolvendo duas aplicações uma web (serviço) e outra mobile(consome o serviço), no apk o usuario enviar formularios para a aplicação web, daí gostaria de criar uma especie de notificação para cada novo formulario que o servidor receber. Parecido com o que ha no proprio site do stack overflow. Como poderia fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ja na pagina onde lista todos os formularios recebidos, como poderia da um reload no datatable sem precisar atualizar toda a pagina?

Meu list de formularios recebidos na aplicaçao web:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<!-- JQUERY DATATABLE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document)
        .ready(
                function() {
                    $('#myTable3')
                            .DataTable(
                                    {
                                        "language" : {
                                            "sEmptyTable" : "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                                            "sInfo" : "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                                            "sInfoEmpty" : "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                                            "sInfoFiltered" : "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                                            "sInfoPostFix" : "",
                                            "sInfoThousands" : ".",
                                            "sLengthMenu" : "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                                            "sLoadingRecords" : "Carregando...",
                                            "sProcessing" : "Processando...",
                                            "sZeroRecords" : "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                                            "sSearch" : "Pesquisar",
                                            "oPaginate" : {
                                                "sNext" : "Próximo",
                                                "sPrevious" : "Anterior",
                                                "sFirst" : "Primeiro",
                                                "sLast" : "Último"
                                            },
                                            "oAria" : {
                                                "sSortAscending" : ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                                                "sSortDescending" : ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                });
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">

<div class="panel-body">
<input type="hidden" name="denuncia.id" value="${d?.id}" />
<table id="myTable3"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-over">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Rua</th>
            <th>Bairro</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        #{list items:denuncias, as:'d'}
        <tr>
            <td>${d.nome}</td>
            <td>${d.rua}</td>
            <td>${d.bairro}</td>
            <td>${d.cidade}</td>
            <td>${d.data}
                <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                    <a href="@{denuncias.remover(d.id)}" class="trash" data-toggle="confirmation" data-btn-ok-label="Sim" data-btn-ok-class="btn-success" data-btn-cancel-label="Não"
                        data-btn-cancel-class="btn-danger" data-title="Remover denuncia"    data-content="Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Remover</span></a> 
                    <a href="@{denuncias.detalhes(d.id)}" class="flag"><span    class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> Detalhes</span></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        #{/list}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Os dados dessa tabela `#myTable3` não parecem que estão sendo carregados com o datatables. Aparentemente você usa uma especie de template engine, no lado servidor, para criar toda a tabela, e quando chega no cliente você aplica o datatables. Isso torna dificil você fazer o datatables dar um reload sem recarregar a pagina. Pois para isso você teria que usar um `table.ajax.reload();`, conforme a [documentação](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()). Para atualizar a pagina você poderia usar sockets ou fazer requisições ajax regurlamente.

Comment: Veja isso, é mais ou menos o que você quer fazer, pode ajudar: [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265987/enviar-um-comando-sem-atualizar-a-pagina/267128#267128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara se você quer algo em tempo real você deve utilizar WebSockets, que é um protocolo TCP que permite comunicação full-duplex. Para isso você deveria trabalhar com o protocolo e com a API WebSockets para implementa-lo. Mas vou facilitar pra você pois sofri muito pra chegar em algo com essa maravilhosa tecnologia. Seguinte, eu usava PHP e precisava de trabalhar com ele para esses WebSOckets, dai surgiu o Ratchet, uma biblioteca que te permite trabalhar com o Wbs através do PHP. Enfim, assista um video que tem Ratchet no titulo nesse site: http://code-squad.com/curso/PHP-Conference-Brasil-2014-palestras

Nele você vai entender o WebSocket e como usar o Ratchet.

Agora o seguinte, a notificação seria enviada em tempo real, mas e se o usuario não estiver online? então você precisa armazenar o formulario/notificação no banco de dados e o gatilho para armazenar seria exatamente o conn.send(AÇÃO DE ARMAZENAR E PROPAGAR A NOTIFICACAO) do Ratchet. A partir dai cara, aprenda a usar mais o WebSockets para que os usuários só se comuniquem com o servidor e não com outros usuários(Isso eu ainda n sei fazer, qro aprender tbm kkkkk).

Comment: vlw pela dica cara. Pelo jeito vou apanhar um pouco ate conseguir.